# Handling errors in Rails.cache.fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails.cache to cache a response from an API:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("key") do 
  api.get "/api/data"
  api.body
end
```

The API isn't very reliable, and occasionally I get a 500 error.  I'd like to avoid caching the 500 response.

```
Rails.cache.fetch("key") do 
  api.get "/api/data"
  if api.body.meta.status == 500
    # Bail out, Goose!
  end
  api.body
end
```

I would rather not raise an exception.  What is the best way to "bail out" of the block without caching?

Comment: IMPORTANT: just found a major Ruby gotcha. Returning from a block will return from the parent method. Best to not "return" but rather allow the last statement to be the block's return value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into this myself and it looks like a `break` will solve our problems. I just tested this locally against the memory_store and the dalli_store and it avoids caching the block. So for your example, try something like this:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("key") do 
  api.get "/api/data"
  break if api.body.meta.status == 500
  api.body
end
```

As a side note, if using the dalli_store it will not cache nil values so you can just return nil from the block.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If you read the code for ActiveSupport::Cache::fetch it calls delete_entry right away if the entry is expired.

Comment: This is really weird... Normally using `break` like this would just return nil from the block, that's not what's happening here. You can `break "Some value"` and that value *won't* get cached. The break really does skip the caching. It's not the same as returning `nil` from the block, because (except for dalli_store, apparently) returning `nil` could just cause `nil` to be cached. Again, that's not what happens. I don't understand how this works, but it definitely works like this with the memory_store

Answer (score 2):

I would not use fetch, in this case, and in most cases.

Fetch make you account for all flow control cases using exception handling as your only mechanism for flow control(!).

Instead, use the read and write methods for the cache, using normal flow control that results in the behavior you want. Fetch is fast and fancy, but comes with extra baggage that you aren't going to be happy with once you have to actually support the software you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
 module CacheExtensions
  class << self
    # This allows caching with an expiration, but if there is an exception thrown from the block that produces
    # the cache value, it uses the old value from the cache, retrying occasionally. The trick is to
    # not put an expiration on the cache value, but on a separate generated key, because Rails.cache.read honors
    # expirations set earlier. I'm surprised Rails.cache.fetch doesn't just handle this.
    #
    # key - the cache key to read and update if needed
    # expiration - how long the key should be good for under normal circumstances
    # retry_expiration - how long between retries if the block raises an exception. if expiration is long, you may want to
    # make this shorter.
    # block - should return the updated value, or raise an exception if it can't be retrieved
    #
    # Inspired by https://github.com/ReliveRadio/reliveradio-website/blob/4874cf4158361c73a693e65643d9e7f11333d9d6/app/helpers/external_api_helper.rb
    def fetch_with_rescue(key, expiration, retry_expiration)
      freshness_key = 'ExpirationFor_' + key
      result = Rails.cache.read(key)
      freshness_result = Rails.cache.read(freshness_key)

      if freshness_result.blank? || result.blank?
        begin
          result = yield
          Rails.cache.write(key, result)
          Rails.cache.write(freshness_key, 'fresh', expires_in: expiration)
        rescue StandardError => error
          Rails.cache.write(freshness_key, 'retrying', expires_in: retry_expiration)
          Rails.logger.error("Got error #{error} attempting to update cache #{key}. Using saved value for #{retry_expiration} additional time.")
        end
      end

      return result
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: BTW this is written to assume the block will raise an exception if it can't get the new value. If it returns nil instead, either adjust it to check the error code and raise, or modify the code above to check for nil.